# Parameter binding to a VO with @Form- RestEasy - JAX-Rs

Tags: java, forms, parameters, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a few variables as `@PathParam`. I want to put them in a Bean and accept all of them in one.

```
public void show( @PathParam("personId"> String personId, 
                  @PathParam("addressId") String addressId 
                  @Context HttpRequest request) {
       // Code
}
```

Now I would like to put all of the parameters in a Bean/VO with `@Form` argument.
My class:

```
class RData {
    private String personId;
    private String addressId;
    private InputStream requestBody;

    @PathParam("personId")
    public void setPersonId(String personId) {
         this.personId = personId;
    }

    @PathParam("addressId")
    public void setAddressId(String addressId) {
         this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    // NOW HERE I NEED TO BIND HttpRequest Context object  to request object in my VO.
    // That is @Context param in the original method.
}
```

My method would change to:

```
public void show( @Form RData rData) {
       // Code
}
```

My VO class above contains what I need to do.
So I need to map `@Context HttpRequest request` to `HttpRequest` instance variable in my VO.

How to do that? Because it does not have an attribute name like `@PathParam`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject `@Context` values into properties just like the form, path, and header parameters.

Example Resource Method:

```
@POST
@Path("/test/{personId}/{addressId}")
public void createUser(@Form MyForm form)
{
    System.out.println(form.toString());
}
```

Example Form Class:

```
public class MyForm {

    private String personId;
    private String addressId;
    private HttpRequest request;

    public MyForm() {

    }

    @PathParam("personId")
    public void setPersonId(String personId) {
         this.personId = personId;
    }

    @PathParam("addressId")
    public void setAddressId(String addressId) {
         this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    public HttpRequest getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    @Context
    public void setRequest(HttpRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("MyForm: [personId: '%s', addressId: '%s', request: '%s']", 
                this.personId, this.addressId, this.request);
    }
}
```

Url:

```
http://localhost:7016/v1/test/1/1
```

Output:

```
MyForm: [personId: '1', addressId: '1', request: 'org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletInputMessage@15d694da']
```

Comment: Would you be able to put a complete example? I tried even without @Context param. The binding just did not work.

Comment: What version of resteasy are you using?  I just looked in the docs and I don't see any mention of injecting "@Context" into "@Form" like I have seen in previous versions of resteasy.

Comment: @Kevin - I just created the example above and the HttpRequest was injected correctly.  I am using version 2.3.6 of RestEasy.

Comment: I am just using <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
<artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>

Comment: @Kevin - See my edited answer.  I added the code that I used to prove it works.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would add an answer for those that are using pure JAX-RS not not RestEasy specifically. Faced with the same problem, and surprised that JAX-RS doesn't have out-of-box support for http Form binding to Java Objects, I created a Java API to marshal/unmarshal java objects to forms, and then used that to create a JAX-RS messagebody reader and writer.

https://github.com/exabrial/form-binding